# ASP.NET Core run background task on given hours

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to run a task that performs a database update at the given hours. I'm not sure if this is the correct way, or if is there a way to register this task to run at specific hours that i can parameterize?

```
    internal class TimedHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ProductionContext _context;

        public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger, ProductionContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting.");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWork(object state)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is working.");

            if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == new TimeSpan(6, 58, 0) ||
             DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == new TimeSpan(14, 58, 0) ||
             DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == new TimeSpan(22, 58, 0))
            {
                var registos = _context.Registos.Where(r => r.DataFimTurno.HasValue);

                var registosModified = registos;

                foreach (var item in registosModified)
                {
                    item.DataFimTurno = DateTime.Now;
                }

                _context.Entry(registos).CurrentValues.SetValues(registosModified);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping.");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would use https://www.hangfire.io/ for scheduled tasks, it contains a dashboard where you can see if it was sucessful and re queue them

Comment: i know hangfire but it seems a lot to implement, i really only need to update something in database at given hours

Comment: Don't roll your own.  Have a look at something like Quartz.

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2017/12/30/quartznet-3.0-released.html

Comment: The trouble with rolling your own is consistency and reliability. You need to set up some storage to log executions and retries as well as some service that will constantly poll for the next job, along with job reporting & preventing two of the same jobs from starting.

Comment: what is the different from this to hangfire?

Comment: You can check below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667000/ihostedservice-backgroundservice-to-run-on-a-schedule-as-opposed-to-task-delay

Comment: seems like i really have to use a schedule library

Comment: I strongly support @PaulAlanTaylor suggestion by using Quartz.NET. I've used it several times, both on a hobby basis and professionally.

Comment: Take a look at Andrew Lock's blog post regarding Quartz.net - https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: I got hangfire to work, plus the dashboard makes it simple, i want to try quartz and see the difference but seems like it has no dashboard

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `IHostedServices`, you could try below code which will run the task at specific hour:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            //run background task at 11:00:00
            if(currentTime.Hour == 11 && currentTime.Minute == 0 && currentTime.Second == 0)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(currentTime.ToString());
                DoWork();
            }              

        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

If you would like to pass parameters for BackgroundService, you could also register it using DI,refer to

[How to pass parameters for BackgroundService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424082/how-to-pass-parameters-for-backgroundservice)